# How do you relate the laplace transform to time and frequency?

Tags: laplace-transform

I am currently Reading about laplace transforms and their use in linear ODE's with constant coefficients,and I have some understanding that why the" Fourier series" relates to frequency/time transformations,but I am unable to draw the conclusion in the laplace case.

Wikipedia only vaguely explains this ,so a understandable explanation about how that works (and easy to follow)would be appreciated .

Also ,a mini question is that why don't we define a faster growing function (like $e^{t^2}$),so that for a wider range of functions the improper integral would converge?

Comment: See this question:   http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1989957/does-the-laplace-transform-have-any-practical-use-or-provide-any-mathematical-in/1990311#1990311

Comment: @ChristianBlatter I wasn't satisfied with that question /answer as it wasn't quite related to mine.

Comment: You might want to watch the first 15 minutes of [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sZ2qulI6GEk).